Onion Router Raspberry Pi Project
I'm trying to make an Onion Router with my pi (nothing nefarious I promise). However, I'm running into an issue with installing it that I've spent the last couple days trying to fix.
So, I'm following this tutorial [ada fruit] (https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software)
I'm on the very last step for installation:
`country_code=AU
interface=wlan0
ssid=Testy Tester
hw_mode=b
channel=13
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=Testing123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP`

I changed country code to AU, hw_mode to b, channel to 13 (not sure if thats right), ssid to my internet name, wpa passphrase to my internet password. However when I run the code I get this error:
`client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset`

I've tried various channels, wireless networks (home, hotspot, university, etc).
How do I fix this?? Any help with this would be SUPER helpful!
